# Converting VS 2008 Coding and VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

I have a Project in my system VS 2008 , Now I want to start a Project in 2012.

If i Installed VS 2012 then my older project of Vs 2008 also changed to VS 2012

Now i could not open my older project VS 2008 because of New version Installed.

How can i open my older project in VS2008 and also i want VS 2012 for New Projects.

Suggest me to get a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is only "changed" to VS2012 when you first open it in VS2012 (and it will prompt you before running the conversion). If you open the old project in VS2008  it will work fine.

Possibly what you're seeing is that the file association for your solution files is changed, so that they open by default in VS2012. The way around that is to open VS2008 manually and use "Open Solution" to load your old project, instead of opening the project from a direct shortcut.

Comment: I wrongly opened my Project in VS2012, Now i can't open my project in 2008

Comment: @user26853 - Modify the file  by hand.  There are numerous differences between the layout of the XML file.  Using a new project created in VS2008 can help achieve this.  There are far to many changes to list here and it is easily done by you.

Comment: Can you Please tell any one one method to solve this

Comment: Suggest me to solve my problem

Comment: I did. I said "open VS2008 manually and use "Open Solution" to load your old project, instead of opening the project from a direct shortcut." Did you try that?